# How in one tab Ext.tab.Panel output two Ext.grid.Panel. Extjs

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

How to make that in Ext.tab.Panel in tab Mytab1 two Ext.grid.Panel were loaded?
In the app.js file, I get the Ext.tab.Panel:

```
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'BookApp',
    appFolder: 'static/hello_extjs',
    controllers: ['Books'],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            items: [
                {
                    region: 'north',
                    xtype: 'maintab'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

In Ext.tab.Panel I do not know how to correctly form items Mytab1 that would load two Ext.grid.Panel:

```
Ext.define('BookApp.view.MainTab', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'maintab',
    alias: 'widget.maintab',
    title: 'Панель вкладок',
    items: [
        {
            items:  //How to do what would be displayed two grids
                title: 'Mytab1',
            border: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            header: false
        },
        {
            items: 'booklist',//What exactly is necessary to point out that one grid
            title: 'Mytab2',
            border: false,
            layout: 'fit',
            header: false
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your grids in items and call them from `xtype` property: [**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2lfc)

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Your answer helped me